# Если "в частности" заключает предложение, запятая перед ним ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> Вот что привлекает меня в истории и в истории искусства, в частности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что привлекает меня в истории, **и в истории искусства в частности**.

Здесь союз И ― присоединительный, в заданном предложении использована инверсия.

Сравнить: Вот что привлекает меня в истории вообще и  в истории искусства в частности.